# Context html export bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, context, html

Context MKIV html export works perfectly, but: the bibliography in APA produces `----` lines for authors with several publications which disappear in html-rendering. Which is the best way to resolve this problem: 1. for this particular case repeat the name of the author in each publication, that is, to change the parameters of the style 2. make a adjustment to translate the resultant line into an html-coded entity? Can one suggest a solution to both variants?

```
\setupbackend[export=yes]

\usebtxdataset[mkiv-publications.bib]

\usebtxdefinitions[apa]

\starttext

\placelistofpublications[method=dataset]

\stoptext
```

Comment: I have added a MWE for you.  Please always add one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule is drawn by the command `\blackrule` which is apparently not exported to XML.  A quick workaround would be to write an `\emdash` instead of the rule.

```
\setupbackend[export=yes]

\usebtxdataset[mkiv-publications.bib]

\usebtxdefinitions[apa]

\startsetups apa:list:sameauthor:rule
    \emdash
\stopsetups

\starttext

\placelistofpublications[method=dataset]

\stoptext
```